# Can the Oracle "with clause" be moved or rearranged such that the first keyword is select?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have an application that I can enter in arbitrary select statements, and it has some validation routine going on where if it sees something other than "select" as the first keyword, it refuses to play nice.

I'm trying to use a query of this form:

```
with mytable as (select something from sometable)
select somestuff from mytable
connect by level <= 50
```

This returns the correct value when ran from SQL Developer, and would no doubt do the same if the application wasn't trying to be clever. Is it possible to rearrange the order such that the *with clause* is written elsewhere other than the first line? Are there any other tricks that might fool this thing?

Comment: If you are only going to use that subquery once, don't use the with keyword at all.  Just give the subquery an alias and it will be a derived table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in a subselect is all I can think of

```
Select * from 
  (with mytable as 
  (select something from sometable) 
   select somestuff from mytable connect by level <= 50) B
```